# Why does a code run after setScreen() in LIBGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a simple menu screen with four buttons and event listeners on each of them. In this listeners I execute `changeScreen()` method, which changes the screen by invoking `setScreen()`. Screens change without problems but why does the code after `changeScreen()` in the body of the `changed()` method run.

```
openFile.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        parent.changeScreen(Hren.OPENFILE);
        System.out.println("Why do I see this text when I am in OPENFILE screen");
    }
 });
```

Comment: dude you need to give more code, we are not reading in minds. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If i am not mistaken this is an asynchronous problem. Changing the screen does not remove the listener from the openFile. And that is because the `parent.changeScreen` is not a terminate call ( terminate the function like return or throw exception. ) Thus your code keeps running till the end of the function

Comment: Whether the listener is removed or not is irrelevant. Whether this is synchronous (it is) or not is irrelevant. A method always runs until it returns.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes my explain was bad.. I was thinking of thread killing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You are a genius.

Comment: changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) is just a method and setScreen() is just a method and nothing more. Did I understand right that sequence of execution is: ... setScreen(), rest of changed(), render(), render(), render() forever ...?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called the call stack in most programming languages. Every method you call will run until it hits a line that calls `return`. (There is an implicit `return` right at the end of the method if you don't type one.) When you call a method, it is added to the stack so it is run next before it is popped off and execution can continue from where it was added.

In this case, once `changeScreen()` returns, it is popped off the stack and execution continues on through the rest of this `changed()` method. It doesn't matter that whatever called it is currently no longer queued for drawing on the screen. The call stack doesn't know or care about that.